# SQLite - A problem on applying SQL queries to a random database with a batch file

Tags: sqlite, batch-file

**Question 1.** I made a batch file (let it be Sample.bat) with this code:

```
@echo off
if %1== goto end
cd %~dp0
sqlite3 "%~1" ".read Sample.sql"
:end
```

And I downloaded `sqlite3.exe` from the homepage and put it on the same folder as the batch file. The problem is, when I drag & drop database file on it (on Windows Explorer), it works only if the database file is on the same folder as the batch file, and fails otherwise. How can I fix it?

**Question 2.** What is the difference between ".load Sample.sql" and ".read Sample.sql"? It's hard to google.

Comment: Please change `if %1== goto end` to `If "%~1" == "" GoTo end`, and `cd %~dp0` to `CD /D "%~dp0"`.

Comment: Please also take a look at [this page](https://sqlite.org/cli.html), for a quick look at the dot commands for an idea of what they do.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for Question 2. For Question 1, I tried your solution, but nothing was changed.

Comment: Cyriel, those were just a fix for your invalid line and an improvement, _(recommended syntax)_, for your other. Without some idea of what the input argument is, and how it is passed, confirmation of the location of `Sample.sql`, what you intend to happen, and what is actually happening, it is difficult for us to assist you.

Comment: Sorry for late comment. `Sample.sql` is on the same folder with the batch file and `sqlite3.exe`, as you can guess from "It worked when the database file is on the same folder as them".